# Number system converter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, number-systems

This program converts from number system A to number system B as soon as you input something in it, as a rookie it took a lot of thinking to make it work  a seamless and fool-proof way.

It converts the number from base A to base 10 and then to base B because the formulas are always the same.

It is based on this website's version: https://codebeautify.org/all-number-converter

That said i still wanted to post the code here to receive feedback on the way it's structured so i don't pick up some bad habits:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainApplication:
    numtoletter = {
        0: "0",
        1: "1",
        2: "2",
        3: "3",
        4: "4",
        5: "5",
        6: "6",
        7: "7",
        8: "8",
        9: "9",
        10: "A",
        11: "B",
        12: "C",
        13: "D",
        14: "E",
        15: "F",
        16: "G",
        17: "H",
        18: "I",
        19: "J",
        20: "K",
        21: "L",
        22: "M",
        23: "N",
        24: "O",
        25: "P",
        26: "Q",
        27: "R",
        28: "S",
        29: "T",
        30: "U",
        31: "V",
        32: "W",
        33: "X",
        34: "Y",
        35: "Z",
    }

    lettertonum = {
        "0": 0,
        "1": 1,
        "2": 2,
        "3": 3,
        "4": 4,
        "5": 5,
        "6": 6,
        "7": 7,
        "8": 8,
        "9": 9,
        "A": 10,
        "B": 11,
        "C": 12,
        "D": 13,
        "E": 14,
        "F": 15,
        "G": 16,
        "H": 17,
        "I": 18,
        "J": 19,
        "K": 20,
        "L": 21,
        "M": 22,
        "N": 23,
        "O": 24,
        "P": 25,
        "Q": 26,
        "R": 27,
        "S": 28,
        "T": 29,
        "U": 30,
        "V": 31,
        "W": 32,
        "X": 33,
        "Y": 34,
        "Z": 35,
    }

    numbercheck = {
        2: "01",
        3: "012",
        4: "0123",
        5: "01234",
        6: "012345",
        7: "0123456",
        8: "01234567",
        9: "012345678",
        10: "0123456789",
        11: "0123456789A",
        12: "0123456789AB",
        13: "0123456789ABC",
        14: "0123456789ABCD",
        15: "0123456789ABCDE",
        16: "0123456789ABCDEF",
        17: "0123456789ABCDEFG",
        18: "0123456789ABCDEFGH",
        19: "0123456789ABCDEFGHI",
        20: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ",
        21: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK",
        22: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL",
        23: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLM",
        24: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMN",
        25: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO",
        26: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP",
        27: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ",
        28: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR",
        29: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS",
        30: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST",
        31: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU",
        32: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV",
        33: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW",
        34: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX",
        35: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY",
        36: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    }

    base = ["Base-2 (Binary)", "Base-3", "Base-4", "Base-5", "Base-6", "Base-7", "Base-8 (Octal)", "Base-9", "Base-10 (Decimal)", "Base-11", "Base-12", "Base-13", "Base-14", "Base-15", "Base-16 (Hexadecimal)", "Base-17",
            "Base-18", "Base-19", "Base-20", "Base-21", "Base-22", "Base-23", "Base-24", "Base-25", "Base-26", "Base-27", "Base-28", "Base-29", "Base-30", "Base-31", "Base-32", "Base-33", "Base-34", "Base-35", "Base-36", ]

    inputnum = "" # number to be converted
    outputnum = "" # result of the conversion
    inputbase = "" # base of the inputnum
    outputbase = "" # base of the outputnum
    outputnumto = 0 # where the outputnum goes
    varx = 0 # to make it so the function "convert" doesn't run when the value of stringvar is changed not through user input
    vary = 0 # to make it so the "convert" function doesn't run infinitely at line 233

    def __init__(self, master): # setting up the window and calling functions for gui creation
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Number system converter")
        self.master.geometry("600x200")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.label_title, self.label_equals = self.create_text()
        self.stringvar_number1, self.entry_number1, self.stringvar_number2, self.entry_number2 = self.create_number_input()
        self.combobox_base1, self.combobox_base2 = self.create_base_selection()

    def create_text(self):
        label_title = tk.Label(self.master, text="NUMBER SYSTEM CONVERTER", font=(
            "Calibri", 20, "bold"), anchor=tk.CENTER,)
        label_title.place(x=100, y=0, width=400, height=50)

        label_equals = tk.Label(self.master, text="=", font=(
            "Calibri", 20), anchor=tk.CENTER, justify=tk.CENTER)
        label_equals.place(x=275, y=65, width=50, height=30)

        return label_title, label_equals

    def create_number_input(self): # entry(s) for input and stringvars
        stringvar_number1 = tk.StringVar()
        stringvar_number1.set("1")
        stringvar_number1.trace("w", lambda x, y, z: self.convert(2))

        entry_number1 = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=stringvar_number1, font=(
            "Calibri", 16), borderwidth=0, bg="white",)
        entry_number1.place(x=50, y=65, width=225, height=30)

        stringvar_number2 = tk.StringVar()
        stringvar_number2.set("1")
        stringvar_number2.trace("w", lambda x, y, z: self.convert(1))

        entry_number2 = tk.Entry(self.master, textvariable=stringvar_number2, font=(
            "Calibri", 16), borderwidth=0, bg="white",)
        entry_number2.place(x=325, y=65, width=225, height=30)

        return stringvar_number1, entry_number1, stringvar_number2, entry_number2

    def create_base_selection(self): # combobox(s) for selecting the base
        combobox_base1 = ttk.Combobox(
            self.master, values=self.base, font=("Calibri", 14), state="readonly")
        combobox_base1.place(x=50, y=100, width=225, height=30)

        popdown_base1 = self.master.tk.call(
            "ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow", combobox_base1)
        self.master.tk.call(f"{popdown_base1}.f.l",
                            "configure", "-font", "Calibri 14")

        combobox_base1.current(0)

        combobox_base1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",
                            lambda x: self.inputbase_or_outputbase())

        combobox_base2 = ttk.Combobox(
            self.master, values=self.base, font=("Calibri", 14), state="readonly")
        combobox_base2.place(x=325, y=100, width=225, height=30)

        popdown_base2 = self.master.tk.call(
            "ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow", combobox_base2)
        self.master.tk.call(f"{popdown_base2}.f.l",
                            "configure", "-font", "Calibri 14")

        combobox_base2.current(0)

        combobox_base2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",
                            lambda x: self.inputbase_or_outputbase())

        return combobox_base1, combobox_base2

    def inputbase_or_outputbase(self): # determining if a base belongs to the input or output number
        if self.outputnumto == 2:
            self.inputbase = self.combobox_base1.get()[5:7]
            self.outputbase = self.combobox_base2.get()[5:7]
        elif self.outputnumto == 1:
            self.inputbase = self.combobox_base2.get()[5:7]
            self.outputbase = self.combobox_base1.get()[5:7]

        if self.vary == 0:
            self.convert(self.outputnumto)

    def convert(self, n): # determining which entry modified last (through stringvar tracing) + the process of converting input number in output base (outputbase determined through the previous function)
        if self.varx == 1:
            self.varx = 0
            return

        self.outputnumto = n

        if self.outputnumto == 2:
            self.inputnum = self.entry_number1.get().upper()

        elif self.outputnumto == 1:
            self.inputnum = self.entry_number2.get().upper()

        self.vary = 1
        self.inputbase_or_outputbase()
        self.vary = 0

        if not self.inputbase or not self.outputbase:
            return

        for x in self.inputnum:
            if not x in self.numbercheck[int(self.inputbase)]:
                if self.outputnumto == 1:
                    self.varx = 1
                    self.stringvar_number1.set("Invalid input")
                elif self.outputnumto == 2:
                    self.varx = 1
                    self.stringvar_number2.set("Invalid input")
                return

        base10num = self.convert_to_base10(self.inputbase, self.inputnum)
        outputnum = self.convert_to_baseo(self.outputbase, base10num)

        if self.outputnumto == 1:
            self.varx = 1
            self.stringvar_number1.set(outputnum)
        elif self.outputnumto == 2:
            self.varx = 1
            self.stringvar_number2.set(outputnum)

    def convert_to_base10(self, inputbase, inputnum): # converting inputnum to base10
        inputbase = int(inputbase)
        inputnum = inputnum[::-1]
        multiply = 1
        base10num = 0

        for x in inputnum:
            x = self.lettertonum[x]
            base10num = (x * multiply) + base10num
            multiply = multiply * inputbase

        return base10num

    def convert_to_baseo(self, outputbase, base10num): # converting inputnum to outputbase
        outputbase = int(outputbase)
        base10num = int(base10num)
        outputnum = ""

        while base10num > 0:
            outputnum = outputnum + self.numtoletter[base10num % outputbase]
            base10num = base10num // outputbase

        outputnum = outputnum[::-1]

        return outputnum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In no particular order:

- `numtoletter` and similar variables and method names should be `num_to_letter` (lower_snake_case)
- `numtoletter` and `lettertonum` should not be written out like that, and should be formed via loops - which computers are good at
- `numbercheck` is not necessary if you listen for `ValueError`s from `int()`
- `base` should also be formed via a loop
- you have a bunch of symbols initialized in static scope of your class. Moving your constants between there and global scope is debatable, but `inputnum` through `varx` should not exist at all.
- [Don't call things `master`](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-GitHub-renamed-its-master-branch-to-main).
- You've accepted a parent widget parameter to your constructor - this is good. In theory it means that you could populate *any* widget with your converter. However, it also means that your class instance does not *own* the parent, and so it should not be responsible for setting title and geometry.
- Your title label is unnecessary - you've already set a title on the parent window decorator.
- You should generally avoid `place` and instead favour grid-like placement. This is less fragile and manual. You can still add padding, etc. if you want to.
- Some of your visual modifications such as giant font aren't all that useful. Generic UI scaling in tkinter is [sort of a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution), and would still require that you modify your fonts; but my opinion is: the user has control of their window manager, and all self-respecting window managers have some kind of utility to apply zoom.
- You do not need to save references to any of your widgets - just your variables.
- You should always pass parent, `name` and `value` parameters to your tk variables on construction. This will obviate your first call to `set`.
- Avoid lambdas. You can just make a bound method on your class for your traces. Do not fake the names `x`, `y` and `z`; those are actually `name`, `index` and `mode`.
- When tk sets the background colour of a combo box to grey, it's trying communicate something: that the input half of the combo box is read-only, and can only be changed via dropdown. My opinion is that it's confusing to set this to white, and the default should be left.
- You used `StringVar` on your inputs - good! You should do the same with your combo boxes! This will obviate your call to `current()`.
- Don't call `bind` at all. This whole machinery of input-or-output-base and last-known-edited-input is too complicated. You can figure out which input was just edited by which trace was called; and assuming that a change in base of the left-hand side auto-converts the right-hand value is intuitive enough that I don't find it useful to do anything more complex.
- The `n` parameter to `convert` is only ever one of two values, so I recommend changing it to a `forward: bool`. Or, as I've shown, just accept a source and destination group object that holds references to your number and base variables.
- Add PEP484 type hints.
- `trace()` is deprecated and should be `trace_add()`.

### Suggested

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from typing import Tuple, Iterator, Dict, List, Callable


def base_pairs() -> Iterator[Tuple[str, int]]:
    for base in range(2, 37):
        desc = f'Base-{base}'
        name = BASE_NAMES.get(base)
        if name is not None:
            desc += f' ({name})'
        yield desc, base


BASE_NAMES = {
    2: 'Binary',
    8: 'Octal',
    10: 'Decimal',
    16: 'Hexadecimal',
}
BASES: Dict[str, int] = dict(base_pairs())
DEFAULT_BASE = next(iter(BASES.keys()))
NUM_TO_LETTER: List[str] = [
    *(str(x) for x in range(10)),
    *ascii_uppercase,
]


def convert_to_base(output_base: int, base10_num: int) -> str:
    """converting inputnum to outputbase"""
    output_num = ''

    while base10_num > 0:
        base10_num, remainder = divmod(base10_num, output_base)
        output_num = NUM_TO_LETTER[remainder] + output_num

    return output_num


class InputGroup:
    def __init__(
        self, parent: tk.Tk, index: int,
        convert: Callable[[], None],
    ) -> None:
        self.convert = convert

        self.number_var = tk.StringVar(
            parent, name=f'number{index}', value='1',
        )
        self.set_trace()
        tk.Entry(
            parent, textvariable=self.number_var,
        ).grid(row=0, column=2*index)

        self.base_var = tk.StringVar(
            parent, name=f'base{index}', value=DEFAULT_BASE,
        )
        self.base_var.trace_add(mode='write', callback=self.trace)

        names = tuple(BASES.keys())
        ttk.Combobox(
            parent, values=names, state='readonly',
            textvariable=self.base_var,
        ).grid(row=1, column=2*index)

    def set_trace(self) -> None:
        self.trace_id = self.number_var.trace_add(mode='write', callback=self.trace)

    def trace(self, name: str, index: str, mode: str) -> None:
        self.convert()

    @property
    def base(self) -> int:
        return BASES[self.base_var.get()]

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        value = self.number_var.get().upper()
        return int(value, self.base)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value: int) -> None:
        as_base = convert_to_base(self.base, value)
        self.set_output(as_base)

    def set_output(self, value: str) -> None:
        self.number_var.trace_remove(mode='write', cbname=self.trace_id)
        try:
            self.number_var.set(value)
        finally:
            self.set_trace()


class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk) -> None:
        """setting up the window and calling functions for gui creation"""
        self.parent = parent

        tk.Label(self.parent, text='=').grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.groups = (
            InputGroup(parent, index=0, convert=self.convert_forward),
            InputGroup(parent, index=1, convert=self.convert_backward),
        )

    def convert_forward(self) -> None:
        self.convert(*self.groups)

    def convert_backward(self) -> None:
        self.convert(*self.groups[::-1])

    def convert(self, source: InputGroup, dest: InputGroup) -> None:
        try:
            dest.value = source.value
        except ValueError:
            dest.set_output('Invalid input')


def main() -> None:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Number system converter')
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```